# Challenge! Complex MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

We are coding a small search engine. Database Tables:

```
Documents (DocumentID, Title, Abstract, Author, ...)
InvertedIndex (DocumentID, Word, Count)
Stopwords (Word)
```

Where InvertedIndex has an entry for each word in each Document and the number of times it appears. Stopwords is simply a list of words that I dont care about. The engine is queried with lists of terms separated by or. For example:

- term1 term2
- term1 or term2
- term1 term2 or term3

...etc. Search results based on Relevance, calculated for each document with the boolean extended model. and-ed terms (all terms that are not ored) are multiplied and ors are summed. For example, considering the query term1 term2 or term3, if the terms appear in a document 3, 4, and 5 times respectively, the document relevance would be (3*4)+5 = 12. Also, ignore terms that exist in Stopwords.

OK Now... my professor has told us that calculating the relevance for all documents can be done in a single query. That's what I need help on.

I've prepared some pseudocode for the example query *term1 term2 or term3*. So this is how I would calculate the relevance for every document, but I would like to perform a single MySQL query instead. I include this just as clarification for the relevance formula.

```
foreach document
    relevance = 0
    foreach term_set // where (term1 term2) would be a term_set and (term3) would be the other
        product = 1
        foreach term
            if term not in stopwords
                SELECT Count FROM InvertedIndex WHERE Word=term AND DocumentID=document
                product *= Count
        relevance += product
```

*(EXP(SUM(LOG(COALESCE(Column,1)))* apparently is a way to perform [aggregate multiplication](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/166184).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this was a chore to get through. It's 2 oclock and I probably didnt explain this very well.

Comment: It's easier to answer with "the right" answer if your question is less open. You describe what you're working on, but not where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue, this might help you get started (but you'll have to check syntax, since my MySQL is rusty):

```
Select DocumentId, Word, Count
From Documents
Inner Join InvertedIndex On Documents.DocumentID = InvertedIndex.DocumentID
Where Word In (term1, term2, term3)
```

This query would give you a list of DocumentIds, the "search" terms, and the count for each document that contains the search term.  You can use this as a starting point for aggregating on DocumentId, using a Group By DocumentId, and then figuring your aggregate multiplication function (which I kindly leave to you).

I haven't worked with MySQL enough to know how to exclude the words in the Stopwords table (you can use EXCEPT in SQL Server) but something like this might work:

```
Select DocumentId, Word, Count
From Documents
Inner Join InvertedIndex On Documents.DocumentID = InvertedIndex.DocumentID
Where Word In (term1, term2, term3)
And Where Not Exists (
    Select DocumentId, Word, Count
    From Documents
    Inner Join InvertedIndex On Documents.DocumentID = InvertedIndex.DocumentID
    Inner Join Stopwords On InvertedIndex.Word = Stopwords.Word
    Where Word In (term1, term2, term3)
)
```

Good luck with your assignment.  Let us know how it turns out!